# pyqt QTimeEdit/QDateTimeEdit now showing seconds

Tags: pyqt

I have a QTimeEdit in my main gui window which is supposed to show the time in some sort of HH:mm:ss.zzz format

```
    self.te_start_time = QDateTimeEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.te_start_time.setMaximumSize(QSize(150, 16777215))
    self.te_start_time.setObjectName("te_start_time")
    self.te_start_time.setDisplayFormat("HH:mm:ss.zzz")
    self.te_start_time.setTime(QTime(9, 5, 50))
```

However it does not show the seconds. It shows

```
9:05.000 AM
```

It actually seems it completely ignores the setDisplayformat as I can put in any format there or not have the line at all.. it always shows the format hh:mm.zzz

Any idea what I can do to change the format to HH:mm:ss.zzz?

Comment: I see nothing suspicious in your code. Perhaps the format is reset elsewhere in your GUI. Can you make an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can try to reproduce it? Preferable an example that we can just copy-paste-execute

Comment: The display format must be reset somewhere else in your code, because the `AM` part does not appear by default. So the format is acually either "h:mm.zzz A" or "h:mm.zzz AP".

Answer (score 0):

As titusjan and ekhumoro pointed out, it was reset somewhere else. QT designer also created a retranslateUI function that reset the format